# Angularfire2 - Get the current user UID and filter list observable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

How do I get the current user UID and use it to filter a list observable?

I tried to use `const currentUser = this.auth.getAuth()`. It returns null and gives me a console.log warning to use `const currentUser = this.auth.subscribe();`

When I console.log the value of currentUser, I get `currentuser: [object Object]` back.

**This is the complete function I made**

```
showUserProfile() {
    //const currentUser = this.auth.getAuth();
    const currentUser = this.auth.subscribe();
    console.log('currentuser: ' + currentUser);
    return this.af.database.list('/', {
      query: {
          orderByChild: 'useruid',
          equalTo: 'miIMjfVx6TgC9zo6jE0yn0I3JbC2' // currentUser.uid 
      }
    });
  }
```

**second attempt with help from Alexander Ciesielski**

Alexander suggested this, but unfortunately it is giving to following error: `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<UserProfile[]>'.`

```
 showUserProfile() {
     this.auth.subscribe(authData => {
      console.log(authData);
      let uid = authData.uid;
      return this.af.database.list('/', {
          query: {
              orderByChild: 'useruid',
              equalTo: uid // currentUser.uid 
          }
      });
  });
 }
```

I tried the following next, sadly `console.log('the output: ' + output);` returns `the output: undefined`

```
showUserProfile() {
    let output;
    this.auth.subscribe(authData => {
      const currentUser = authData.uid;
      console.log('Current User ID: ' + currentUser);

       output = this.af.database.list('/', {
          query: {
              orderByChild: 'useruid',
              equalTo: currentUser
          }
        });
    })
    console.log('the output: ' + output);
    return output;
  }
```

**More information**

The showUserProfile method is called in a different component.

```
userProfiles: FirebaseListObservable<UserProfile[]>

ngOnInit() {
    this.userProfiles = this.authService.showUserProfile();
    console.log('userprofiles: ' + this.userProfiles);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribe()` is asynchronous.

That means you need to pass a `callback function` as a parameter to `.subscribe()`.

When `subscribe()` resolves it will call the `callback function` with the actual data, in this case the auth object.

```
userProfiles: FirebaseListObservable<UserProfile[]>

...

this.auth.subscribe(authData => {
    console.log(authData);
    let uid = authData.uid;
    this.userProfiles = this.af.database.list('/', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'useruid',
            equalTo: uid // currentUser.uid 
        }
    });
});
```

The `userProfiles` list has to be set from inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Can you please tell me how I get the authData outside the function in to equalTo method?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to move the `af.list()` function inside the callback, so it gets called after you have received the uid of the user

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and update. Unfortunately the updated solution is not working for me. I get a error back:

Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<UserProfile[]>'.

Comment: I have updated the original question with more information

Comment: I have updated my answer after your update. You need to set the `userProfiles` from inside the callback since it is asynchronous. You probably also should read more about asynchronous programming in Javascript.